# Trigger a error if first date is greater than second date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, daterangepicker

I'm playing with http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range but need to fire/trigger a error if first date is greater than the second one and also prevent form to be submitted, can any help me to get this working? I notice the parameters:

```
$("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
$("#from").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
```

But didn't know if those did the work. Also if any knows a better tool/library let me know about it.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Datepicker difference in days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142693/jquery-ui-datepicker-difference-in-days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#from").datepicker( );
                    $("#to").datepicker( );
                });
            </script>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#submit_form").click(function() {
                        testDates();
                    });
                });

                function testDates () {
                    var from = new Date(Date.parse($("#from").attr("value")));
                    var to = new Date(Date.parse($("#to").attr("value")));
                    if (from > to) {
                        alert("From is greater than to!");
                        return;
                    }
                    alert("do submit");
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: @arsic-dagran I assume that #submit_form is a button or a element with this ID right? If my form have a action and also has a submit button which sends the form, this code prevents the form to be submitted while conditions are not accomplish?